# Seeded 3D white noise random generator with random access

Tags: random, seed, noise-generator

I have almost zero experience with random generators. I have used the standard rand functions in C and I have used perlin noise.

But now, I need a cube of resolution NxNxN (with N maybe 1e6 or bigger) filled with white noise (no perlin smoothness or whatever) in which I can just "pick" one value and if I repick that same value, it should be the same result every time. It should be seeded, so that if I start the application again, the results need to be the same. It should not be secure or whatever, just random enough so that a human being should not be able to predict values by just thinking. If he really analyses it with a computer, it's ok that it's predictable.

It's like I would use the standard C rand function, setting the seed and doing a nested for loop for the 3 dimensions and generating a random number every time until I reach the coordinate. That is of course terribly slow. I need something that's fast!

I have searched the internet and found a lot and nothing at the same time. Maybe I'm looking for the wrong keywords, but I haven't found anything I can use.

Can anyone help me get started? Code? A link? I don't really care if I understand the algorithms, but it should be easy to implement and use and should especially be fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody seems to be able to answer the question, I have been researching on this and I have solved it with the following sollution:

```
int pseudoRandom(int &seed)
{
    const int a = 16807; // 7^5
    const int m = 2147483647; // 2^31 - 1
    seed = int(unsigned(seed * a) % m);
    return seed;
}
```

I take the above, well known, random function. It's a good function as it can be easily be converted to a shader language, and can easily be expanded to 64-bit ints or something else.

Now, I need to be able to create randoms between 0.0 and ?.? on 3 dimensions and they should always have the same result with the same base-seed, so I took the integer part of every component x, y and z, and a base-seed.

```
int seed = baseseed;
pseudoRandom(seed);
pseudoRandom(seed * (int(x) + seed) * (int(y) + seed) * (int(z) + seed);
```

=> seed is now on the value where I can start making a detailed random grid.
So if I need a detail of 32x32x32 random values, I just generate it here into an array.
If I would have needed a bigger array, I could have done the same step again to generate another layer, like doing:

```
pseudoRandom(seed * (int(x * 100) + seed) * (int(y * 100) + seed) * (int(z * 100) + seed);
```

This way, you're actually quite free on how you randomize, and you have full control of the detail.

This solved my problem.